# How to Create a Custom Bounding Box Around an Object in Fabric.js That Follows Rotations and Persists Across Selection Events?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

**Title**: Custom Bounding Box Follows Rotation But Not After Deselection and Reselection in Fabric.js

**Description**:
Hello fellow developers,

I'm working on a project using **Fabric.js**, and I'm facing an issue with creating a custom bounding box (ruler) around an object. Here are the specifics:

1. Initially, I tried using lines as rulers, but they didn't sync with the object during rotations.
2. Now, I've switched to using a rectangle around the object, which works well during rotation.
3. However, after deselecting the item and then reselecting it (especially when it's already been rotated), the ruler dimensions are not accurate. The ruler doesn't follow the rectangle's position correctly.

**Additional Details**:

- You can see the attached image for reference (unfortunately, I cannot directly share the image here).
- Here's the relevant code snippet I'm using for the custom bounding box:

```js
  export class CustomFabricCanvas extends fabric.Canvas {
    constructor(element, options) {
        super(element, options);
        this.rulerLine = null;
        this.on("selection:created", this.onSelectionCreated.bind(this));
        this.on("selection:cleared", this.onSelectionCleared.bind(this));

        this.on("object:scaling", this.onObjectScaling.bind(this));
        this.on("object:moving", this.onObjectMoving.bind(this));
        this.on("object:rotating", this.onObjectRotating.bind(this));
    }

    onSelectionCreated(event) {
        const activeObject = event.selected;
        if (activeObject?.length > 0) {
            activeObject.forEach((obj) => {
                this.showRuler({ ...obj });
            });
        }
    }

    onSelectionCleared() {
        this.hideRuler();
    }

    showRuler(options) {
        if (!this.rulerLine) {
            this.rulerLine = new fabric.Rect({
                left: options.left + 50, // 
                top: options.top + 50, // +
                height: options.height + 10, 
                width: options.width + 10, 
                stroke: "black",
                strokeWidth: 1,
                fill: "transparent",
                selectable: false,
                originX: "center",
                originY: "center",
                angle: options.angle,
            });

            this.add(this.rulerLine);
            this.renderAll();
        }
    }

    hideRuler() {
        if (this.rulerLine) {
            this.remove(this.rulerLine);
            this.rulerLine = null;
            this.renderAll();
        }
    }
   onObjectRotating(e) {
        const target = e.target;
        console.log(e.target);
        this.rulerLine.set({
            angle: target.angle,
        });

        this.renderAll();
    }

}
```

**Request for Help**:
I need assistance with implementing a solution that ensures the ruler remains proportionate to the object's position even after deselection and reselection. How can I make the rectangle-based ruler persist correctly?

**Image Ref**:

- after rotation
  [image: after rotation]
- before rotation
  [image: before rotation]

---

I attempted to create a custom bounding box (ruler) around an object in Fabric.js. Initially, I used lines as rulers, but they didn’t sync with the object during rotations. Now, I’ve switched to using a rectangle around the object, which works well during rotation.

However, after deselecting the item and then reselecting it (especially when it’s already been rotated), the ruler dimensions are not accurate. The ruler doesn’t follow the rectangle’s position correctly.

I expected the ruler to consistently adjust with the object’s position, even after deselection and reselection.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue run into some errors ... there is no `onObjectScaling` or `onObjectMoving` in your code

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is best seen if you visualize it real time ...

See my sample code below *(mostly your code)*, I changed the function `onObjectRotating` to also set the left and top, that way we can see what you are doing when the rotation event not only at select.

```js
class CustomFabricCanvas extends fabric.Canvas {
    constructor(element, options) {
        super(element, options);
        this.rulerLine = null;
        this.on("selection:created", this.onSelectionCreated.bind(this));
        this.on("selection:cleared", this.onSelectionCleared.bind(this));

        // this.on("object:scaling", this.onObjectScaling.bind(this));
        this.on("object:moving", this.onObjectRotating.bind(this));
        this.on("object:rotating", this.onObjectRotating.bind(this));
    }
    onObjectRotating(e) {
        this.rulerLine.set({
            angle: e.target.angle,
            left: e.target.left + 50,
            top: e.target.top + 50
        });
        this.renderAll();
    }
    onSelectionCreated(event) {
        event.selected.forEach((obj) => {
            this.showRuler({ ...obj });
        });
    }
    onSelectionCleared() {
        this.hideRuler();
    }
    showRuler(options) {
        if (!this.rulerLine) {
            this.rulerLine = new fabric.Rect({
                left: options.left + 50, // 
                top: options.top + 50, // +
                height: options.height + 10, 
                width: options.width + 10, 
                stroke: "black",
                strokeWidth: 1,
                fill: "transparent",
                selectable: false,
                originX: "center",
                originY: "center",
                angle: options.angle,
            });

            this.add(this.rulerLine);
            this.renderAll();
        }
    }
    hideRuler() {
        if (this.rulerLine) {
            this.remove(this.rulerLine);
            this.rulerLine = null;
            this.renderAll();
        }
    }
}

var canvas = new CustomFabricCanvas('a');
var rect = new fabric.Rect({ left: 15, top: 50, height: 50, width: 50 })
canvas.add(rect);
canvas.renderAll();
canvas.setActiveObject(rect);
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/5.3.1/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="a" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

if you want to see a different behavior try without the:

```
originX: "center",
originY: "center",
```

Here is how that visually looks like

[image]
. VS .
[image]

Comment: take a look at this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jke2m0uh/10/)

how do i prevent the ruler from getting wider when rotated ?

can you help me with implementing ruler functionality too ?

Comment: @azr-arch you should ask a new question about that... other people could run into that same problem and your question (& answers) can help them  ... that is how  future developer can benefit from StackOverflow ... keep your questions focus on one issue and as you run into other issues ask other questions ... also remember to upvote those question that are helpful and flag correct answers as such